# What algorithm is being used to set precedence in Recent Reviews Page?

Tags: support, review, top-users

What is the algorithm or method we use on Stack Overflow to set precedence in a Stack Overflow page?

Since I have not completed 20 posts it's all right, but after I 20 posts are completed confusions starts. Here are some points

- I have completed 20 posts at 321, but I got positioned second from the top[image]
- Second, why not first as the person who is first was already in the same position before I completed my 20 posts?
- I have noticed this is *usually* after completing 20 post I reside on top, but whenever Sudarshan is already there, I get second position.
- Is it random?

Comment: Does it really matters?

Comment: No I'm Just curious.. :)

Comment: No, it's not random. You are put in second place to profusely annoy you. Mission completed. ;)

Comment: @Bart many time been putted on first place to please, I don't feed any requisites then too..

Comment: Pretty good chance that it is not random, but undefined (read: in whatever order the database returns the matches).